# Z attribute in field:input Spring Tag

Tags: spring-mvc, input, spring-roo, scaffolding

I'm building an app using SpringRoo, I've generated the repositories, the services and I've done the scaffold of my model classes.

Now I want to customize my User Interface (e.g. create.jspx form), and I cannot understand some behavior in this part:

```
<field:textarea field="cocFile" id="c_com_project_name_domain_ObjectModel_file" z="Wo9RZ7vKscJS74aMwIMY1mqfCsU="/>
```

I cannot see the purpose of the `z` attribute, and I cannot either integrate my own html template in the generated vues. so what `z` stands for in this case, and is it possible to override all generated views by springRoo with custom jsp views.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Anton responded, the z attribute indicates if the item has been modified by the user. To indicate that the item has been personalized must change the value of attribute z by "user-managed" and Roo detect changes made by the user.

You have three options to customize your view jspx:

1- Customize "textarea.tagx".

2- Create a new tagx:

- Make a copy of "textarea.tagx" in the same folder and rename it to "textarea2.tagx".
- Customize the new tagx created.
- To use it you must change "texarea" with "textarea2" in label element, as follows: `<field:textarea2 field = "cocFile" id = "c_com_project_name_domain_ObjectModel_file" z = "user-managed" />`

3- Modify the "render" and "z" attributes:

```
<field:textarea field="cocFile" id="c_com_project_name_domain_ObjectModel_file" render="false" z="user-managed"/>
```

This item is no longer show on the page, and Roo will not generate. Now you can generate your custom code in the jspx page.

Answer (score 2):

Description in spring documentation is -

```
The z attribute represents a hash key for a given element.
The hash key attribute is important for Roo because it helps determining if a user has altered a Roo managed element. 
This is the secret to round-trip support for JSPX files, as you can edit anything at any time yet Roo will be able to merge in changes to the JSPX successfully. 
The hash key shown in the "z" attribute is calculated
```

Read [spring mvc doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-roo/reference/html/base-web.html).